# What do I do with the items I find in toasters?

Tags: wasteland-2

I've repaired a bunch of toasters, but keep finding seemingly worthless items like Toast (duh!), Preparation G, Spray Paint, etc..

Are these items for anything specific?  If so, what items can I find in toasters, and what do I do with each of them?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This is the best list I've found for this so far, I'd imagine something better will get done eventually:

https://forums.inxile-entertainment.com//viewtopic.php?f=10&t=8139

It's a general list of "white" items you can find and known uses.

The ones related to toaster items (so far) are as follows:

> 7" Single - Ag Center Toaster
>   Werewolf - Damonta
>   Turntable
>
> 761 Metro Bus Schedule - Baldwin Hills toaster
>    Maggie - Griffith
>    (?)
>
> Babi Ruth - Angel Oracle Toaster
>   Biggun - Rodia
>   Brute Force skillbook
>
> Baby Wipes - Angel Oracle sewer toaster
>   Portapotty guy - New Citadel (Seal Beach)
>   500 scrap
>
> Blood Staff - Ag Center Toaster **[may have been removed]**
>   Corporal Flitnlock Eggleston - Ranger Citadel
>   Real Blood Staff - Speech check
>
> Contact Lenses - Highpool House Toaster
>   Doctor Baum - Temple of Titan
>   First Aid skill book
>
> Dessicated Juniper Berries -Prison Toaster
>   Ben - Distillery
>   Special Squeezins x3
>
> Depleted Uranium - Temple of Titan Toaster
>   Mercaptain - Ranger Citadel
>   Req and Inventory item
>
> Dog Whistle - Long Beach toaster
>   (?) - Los Alamitos
>   Hard Boiled Egg x50
>
> Doggie Bones - Damonta Toaster
>   Hyaon Drhku - Prison (RSM friendly required)
>   Animal Whisperer Skill book
>
> Faded Photograph - Rick's RV Toaster
>   Deputy Mona Shera - Angel Oracle
>   Energy weapon
>
> Flame Deluge Canticle - Destroyed Titan Valley toaster
>   Isaac Leibowitz - Leve LUpe Mine
>   Mechanical Repair skillbook
>
> Galileo's Telescope - Griffith (Gauntlet) toaster
>   Alex Dupre - Salt Lake Park
>   Unique SMG
>
> Gloves - Playa Del Ray toaster
>   Ethan White - Angel Oracle
>   Milk x3
>
> House of Pies Menu - Los Feliz toaster
>   Johnny Maloney (gravedigger) - Hollywood
>   Diamond encrusted shovel
>
> Leg Lamp - Highpool Underground Toaster
>   Corporal Flitnlock Eggleston - Ranger Citadel
>   Red Ryder BB Gun / 200 BBs
>
> Medal of Honor - RNC Graveyard Toaster
>   Atchison camp vendor comments about it (gives clue about safe in Darwin)
>
> Pocket Knife - Titan Valley toaster
>   Rambeau - Hollywood gun shop
>   Unique bladed weapon
>
> Preparation G - Prison Toaster
>   Sadler - Canyon of Titan (DBM HQ) (Speech check)
>   Charged Round Sniper Rifle
>
> Spray Paint - Radio Tower Cave Toaster
>   Ranger Brass Knucks - Ranger Citadel
>   Brawling Skill book
>
> Toast - Ranger Citadel Toaster
>
> VHS Tape - Los Alamitos toaster
>   Old Man - Long Beach
>   Weaponsmithing skill book

Comment: The ag toaster is still there. It’s in the basement in the room you have to clear all the vines from before the east field ladder.

Answer (score 6):

They are used to give to certain people you find in the wastes. For example the spray can can be given to the guy near the entrance of the Ranger Citadel who is near a wall (he's not far from the 3 guy sitting of the floor).

I have also given some of them to the museum guy inside the Ranger Citadel too.